# POST request with axios ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm new to HTTP requests and trying to do POST request of my form submitting with axios and getting an error 400. I want to send my data to url and it should be seen there in JSON format.

**codesandbox** https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-brook-g3488?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is very clear you are not passing data to axios post method.I am not sure what kind of validation you have in server but it will be look like this

```
axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "https://frosty-wood-6558.getsandbox.com:443/dishes",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    data:{
      name:event.name,
preparation_time:event.preparation_time,
type:event.type,
spiciness_scale:event.spiciness_scale,
    }
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

Since its now throwing error preparation time validation. Not sure what's the validation you have in server side

```
preparation_time: "Wrong format"
```

Comment: thanks yeah I missed data. I don't have any validation anywhere, I'm just learning hot to do http requests